# Resolve guava conflict between spark core and azure key vault dependency

Tags: java, azure, maven, apache-spark, azure-keyvault

I am trying out a spark application in java which needs to connect to Azure Key-vault and fetch some secrets and process data after reading from a blob storage and push to a SQL Server table. Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>hdinsightSample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>hdinsightSample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.my.package.hdinsightSample.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>repackaged.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>com.google.guava:*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After running the jar file or running the code from Eclipse I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:682)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:89)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1086)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:739)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:879)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:862)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClientImpl.getSecretDelegate(KeyVaultClientImpl.java:2938)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClientImpl.access$1800(KeyVaultClientImpl.java:92)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClientImpl$82.call(KeyVaultClientImpl.java:2928)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClientImpl$82.call(KeyVaultClientImpl.java:2924)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.deliverResponse(CallArbiter.java:120)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.emitResponse(CallArbiter.java:102)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:46)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10238)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10205)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:444)
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:341)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClientImpl.getSecret(KeyVaultClientImpl.java:2868)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClient.getSecret(KeyVaultClient.java:862)
    at com.my.package.hdsinsightSample.utils.KeyVaultUtils.getSecret(KeyVaultUtils.java:12)
    at com.my.package.hdinsightSample.App.main(App.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:591)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:879)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:862)
    ... 36 more
```

This is because to fetch the secret from key vault it uses `guava` jar but `guava` jar complied by default is 11.0.2 (present in spark-core dependecny) whereas the correct version it should be using is 20 (present in the Azure Key-Vault dependency). I tried shading the jar as shown in the pom above but the issue remains the same.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small project with the same dependencies and the dependency tree shows the Guava dependency actually comes from `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:jar:2.10.1`. Regardless of that, the simplest way to get rid of this problem is to explicitly state which Guava version you want your project to use in your POM (ideally the same as the one in Key Vault in this case):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, there is [a new set of libraries](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/keyvault) for Azure Key Vault with improved APIs and additional functionality, which also do not rely on Guava, so that is an alternative approach you can take if you also want to update your code base :)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-certificates</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3/version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-keys/artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3/version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3/version>
</dependency>
```